# rspec --dry run and bundle exec rspec have different count of examples

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

I see that when I run `bundle exec rspec --dry-run` I get around 800 examples but when I run
`bundle exec rspec` the number of examples is significantly lower.

How can I debug this or Identify what tests did not run?

Comment: Do you really want to spend time debugging instead of just actually running your tests with `bundle exec` or a binstub (`bin/rspec`) like you should be doing in the first place? This indicates that your test are not running with the same set of gems when you run them outside bundler. So don't run them outside of bundler. Problem solved. https://bundler.io/man/bundle-exec.1.html

Comment: Please find one excample that `--dry-run` reports, but the "normal" run doesn't. You'll probably see the reason immediately, if not - post it in the question and ping us. I'll be happy to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check name of your specs. If their names doesn't ending with '_spec.rb' bundle exec rspec will not run them.